# R-programming: How can I change the variable names when I combine lists?

Tags: r, list

I have a data in this format:

```
x = c(list(a=1,b=2),list(a=5,b=6))
```

How can I change it to the following format?

```
x = list(a=1,b=2,a1=5,b1=6)
```

I am aware that I can achieve the above by using

```
names(x)[3:4]=c('a1','b1')
```

but it isn't effective as the the length of each lists vary in the data set that I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `make.unique` and it works for all cases without doing any conversion

```
names(x) <- make.unique(names(x), sep="")
names(x)
#[1] "a"  "b"  "a1" "b1"
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this...

```
as.list(as.data.frame(x))

$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2

$a.1
[1] 5

$b.1
[1] 6
```